# Android - Find existing Child in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I'm adding users and storing their details to my FireBase DataBase. One of my child is Connection Number. Two user should not have the same connection number. So, when I add a new child first it should check for the connection number in my databse. If existed should display the toast. 
This is my code for add users to my database.

```
 conAddBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    key = mdata.push().getKey();

                    final String selectArea = addConSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    final String due = dueET.getText().toString();
                    final int mDue = Integer.parseInt(due);

                    String connectionNum = conNumET.getText().toString();
                    connectionNum = "Connection Number = " + connectionNum;

                    final String number = conNumET.getText().toString();

                    String doorNum = conDoorET.getText().toString();
                    doorNum = "Door Number = " + doorNum;

                    String conName = conNameET.getText().toString();
                    conName = "Name = " + conName;

                    final String name = conNameET.getText().toString();

                    String phoneNum = conPhnNumET.getText().toString();
                    phoneNum = "Phone Number = " + phoneNum;

                    String aadharNum = conAthreNumET.getText().toString();
                    aadharNum = "Aadhar Number = " + aadharNum;

                    String rationNum = conRaCaNumET.getText().toString();
                    rationNum = "Ration Number = " + rationNum;

 ConnectionInformation cInfo = new ConnectionInformation(doc, due, selectArea, finalConnectionNum, finalDoorNum, finalConName, finalPhoneNum, finalAadharNum, finalRationNum,mDue);
                            mdata.child(selectArea).child(key).setValue(cInfo);

                            Connections connect = new Connections(number, name, due, doc);
                            connection.child(selectArea).child(key).setValue(connect);

                            totalConecinArea = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userID).child("Total No of Connections");
                            totalConecinArea.child("Total").child(selectArea).child(key).child(number).setValue(mDue);

                            totalNoConnectionDB.child("Total").child(key).child(number).setValue(mDue);

                            toast("New Connection " + finalConnectionNum + "," + finalConName + " is added");

                            Intent i = new Intent(AddConnection.this, AreaGridActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
```

This is my databse Structure.[DataBase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAGe.jpg)

If you need any extra info kindly ask..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to get the dataSnapShot of your database and add an if statement to check whether the value exists or not. So your code should be like this,

```
connection.child(selectArea).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (ds.child("conecNum").getValue().equals(number)) {
                                toast("Connection Number Already Exists");
                            } else {
                                ConnectionInformation cInfo = new ConnectionInformation(doc, due, selectArea, finalConnectionNum, finalDoorNum, finalConName, finalPhoneNum, finalAadharNum, finalRationNum, mDue);
                                mdata.child(selectArea).child(key).setValue(cInfo);

                                Connections connect = new Connections(number, name, due, doc);
                                connection.child(selectArea).child(key).setValue(connect);

                                totalConecinArea = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userID).child("Total No of Connections");
                                totalConecinArea.child("Total").child(selectArea).child(key).child(number).setValue(mDue);

                                totalNoConnectionDB.child("Total").child(key).child(number).setValue(mDue);

                                toast("New Connection " + finalConnectionNum + "," + finalConName + " is added");

                                Intent i = new Intent(AddConnection.this, AreaGridActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```